# how to write a mysql split string function?

Tags: mysql

In my project.I use this sql to select all the devices;

`select * from devicetable where sn in('xx','xxx','xxxx');`

since the front end only pass the string `'xx,xxx,xxx'`    //The devices number is unknow.

so the sql will become

`select * from devicetable where sn in('xx,xxx,xxxx');` which is not my expected.

any help for me, I'm a front-end developer.

Comment: for back-end which language you used ie Java PHP, Ruby etc

Comment: The back-end only care about data structure(C#/C++),Business logic done by front-end.

Comment: If you're the front end developer, modify the front end to pass the string the way you need it passed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_in_set()`:

```
select *
from devicetable
where find_in_set(sn, 'xx,xxx,xxxx');
```

It is not ideal because it prevents the use of indexes.  But, if you are planning on parsing the string in the database anyway, then the performance should not be a bit issue.